# Is there a limit to the number of HTTP headers in a request?

Tags: rest, http

[I am aware of the limits to the size of the headers in an HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/686217/maximum-on-http-header-values), but I am not able to find any information about limits on the *number* of headers in an HTTP request. Is there a standard for a maximum allowed number of HTTP headers in web servers?

Comment: I discovered this is a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53371496/how-many-headers-are-allowed-in-http-protocol